# Form Validation in a pop up window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

Hi I am displaying a pp up window based on the value stored in a localStorage.In the pop up window there is a form containing email and password.The user has to enter his email and password.Now what I need is that, the email entered by user has to be sent to a url and the url returns a status(either 1 or 0).If the url returns 1 then the user can just continue with the log in process.Otherwise an error message should be shown.The url is in the format http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/**email**/3".Here in the place of email highlighten should come the email entered by user in the form.In this way I have to pass the email.In this way I am doing form validation.But I don't know how to do.
Here is my userinfo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<b>Enter your Email ID and Password</b><br><br>
    <form id="userinfo">
        <label for="user">&nbsp;Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" />
        <br><br>
       <label for="pass">Password&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
       <input type="password" id="pass" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="login" value="Log In" />
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the form in the pop up window
Here is my test.js

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var user  = document.querySelector('input#user');
 var pwd  = document.querySelector('input#pass');
var login = document.querySelector('input#login');

login.addEventListener('click', function() {     

    var userStr = user.value;       

    login();
    window.close();

    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage) {
            bgPage.updateIcon();
        });

}); 
function login(){
  var urlPrefix = 'http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/';
  var urlSuffix = '/3';

   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {

 if (req.readyState == 4) {

   if (req.status == 200) {

       var item=req.responseText;

       if(item==1){  
           localStorage.username=userStr;
           localStorage.password=pwd;

       }
   else{ alert('error');}
   }
  }
  });
  var url = urlPrefix + encodeURIComponent(userStr) + urlSuffix;
 req.open("GET", url);
  req.send(null);
              }


     });
```

This is my javascript.When the user presses the log in button,whatever the user enters in the email textbox gets stored in localStorage.username.Now what I need is that I have to check whether such an email id exists by passing the email to the above specified url.And if it exists only it should be stored in localStorage.username.Please anyone help me. I have tried using the above code.But noting happens.Please help me

Comment: When going to www.calpinemate.com I get blocked by my virus scanner. When going to http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/ or http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/ I get redirected to random sites. Maybe you've been hacked or you're hosting malware. In either case I'd better not help you store logins...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a resource you can edit and use Download Source Code or see live demo here http://purpledesign.in/blog/pop-out-a-form-using-jquery-and-javascript/

It is a contact form. You can change it to validation.
Add a Button or link to your page like this

```
<p><a href="#inline">click to open</a></p>
```

“#inline” here should be the “id” of the that will contain the form.

```
<div id="inline">
 <h2>Send us a Message</h2>
 <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
 <label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
 <br>
 <label for="msg">Enter a Message</label>
 <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea"></textarea>
<button id="send">Send E-mail</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Include these script to listen of the event of click. If you have an action defined in your form you can use “preventDefault()” method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".modalbox").fancybox();
$("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });
$("#send").on("click", function(){
var emailval = $("#email").val();
var msgval = $("#msg").val();
var msglen = msgval.length;
var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);
if(mailvalid == false) {
$("#email").addClass("error");
}
else if(mailvalid == true){
 $("#email").removeClass("error");
 }

 if(msglen < 4) {
 $("#msg").addClass("error");
 }
 else if(msglen >= 4){
 $("#msg").removeClass("error");
 }

 if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
 // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
 // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
 $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");
 //This will post it to the php page
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'sendmessage.php',
 data: $("#contact").serialize(),
 success: function(data) {
 if(data == "true") {
 $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
//Display a message on successful posting for 1 sec
 $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
 setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
 });
 }
 }
 });
 }
 });
 });
</script>
```

You can add anything you want to do in your PHP file.